# Grafana sending alert with the wrong chart image

Tags: docker, grafana

I am using Grafana over Docker.
When setting an email alert I get image of the "Home Dashboard" insted of the alert plot.
How can I get the right plot?

[image: Alert Plot]
[image: Alerting rules & notifications]
[image: Email image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is related to the fact that you are running grafana in Docker but also on subpath - e.g. yourdomain.com/grafana  (and you use e.g. nginx as reverse proxy to route your /grafana path to appropriate container)

There is currently no way of getting images right in such combination as image renderer is unable to work properly with the grafana setting (in /etc/grafana/grafana.ini and /usr/share/grafana/conf/default.ini - both inside grafana docker container):

serve_from_sub_path = true

(It looks like there is some problem with finding the proper path and thus grafana web server will route image renderer to the home path and hence homepage image)

this setting has to be set to false, however, in your configuration grafana will stop working.

The best solution to this is to not use grafana on subpath, but run it on the separate domain e.g. grafana.yourdomanin.com

Adding a subdomain to the existing domain should be easy.
Once you have an extra subdomain, then you need to:

1. change the reverse proxy config to route new domain to the appropriate container
2. change grafana configs to serve_from_sub_path = false
3. update grafana config root url root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/  (not to use local path)

once you do this, images will render correctly.

One observation - I have not managed to run grafana 7.3.4 with image-renderer plugin as once installed, it gave me incompatibility error and killed my grafana completely, but using external docker image renderer.